# How do I add a browse file system button to a Visual Studio app?

Tags: asp.net

I am looking to add a browse button to a visual studio app something simular to the the dialog box in the 'fileupload' tool. I am looking to be able to graphically select any file from my computer or a computer across a network.

Comment: You've tagged this asp.net - do you mean select a file from a web page but not to upload? That won't generally be possible: you'd need an ActiveX control or browser extension which isn't running at low trust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `FileUpload` control...

http://www.dotnet-webhosting.com/aspnet-2-0-tutorials/asp-net-2-0-fileupload.aspx

Otherwise, the SWF uploader is very popular if you want something richer: http://www.swfupload.org/

EDIT:

The `OpenFileDialog` is a WinForms control and there is no equivalent in ASP.NET. When using a `FileUpload` the browser knows to provide you with a file picker to browse your local system. There is no way to replicate this behaviour with some type of local ActiveX control. This is a natural and deliberate limitation of the web, the application **should** not be able to access your local file system apart from in **exceptional and well-defined** circumstances.

Comment: Hi Dave, I guess i asked my question wrong. I am looking for the option to have the OpenFileDialog box. It is the one that browses files on your local pc and allows you to choose one. In my VS it is not in my toolbox, I tried to add it but it doesn't appear. Can you shed any insight on this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I see it in the Windows Forms. I was looking to add it into a webbased application that has the ability to move files across the network at my place of work, per my supervisor. But it looks like I can only do this through Windows Forms. Thanks.